# Stacked Block Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, equations-of-motion

I am confused on a trivial problem here involving Newton's 3rd Law and the FBD of the following problem,

[image]

where the question asks for the differential equation of  motion, with $V_2$ as output and $V_1$ as input. It also asks for the implicit force associating $V_1$ and $V_2$.

The velocity $V_2$ here is relative to $V_1$, while the velocity of $V_1$ is relative to the ground which has no friction with block $M_1$.

My attempts are the following:
[image]

Block 2 is moving at velocity $V = V_1 - V_2$ assuming $V_1 > V_2 $
Force balance on block $M_2$:

$$M_{2}\cdot a_{1} - b\cdot V_{2} = M_2\cdot a_{1}$$
Force balance on block $M_1$:

$$M_{1}\cdot a_{1} = b\cdot V_{2}$$

For the implicit force, I assume it is $F = -b\cdot V_{2}-M_{1}\cdot a_{1}$